# Hide menu item in certain condition

Tags: menus, jquery

I'm using the plugin qTranslate and I have to hide one menu item when the language isn't Italian.

Searching online I created [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mma87/S4rhC/7/)and applied the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

I created the file hide-menu.js and the content is

```
 jQuery('a[href*="/it/noleggio-lungo-termine"]').each(function() {
   $("li#menu-item-9452").hide();
});
```

Then I added in the bottom of the function.php this code

```
   function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'hide-menu', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hide-menu.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
   }
```

but this solution doesn't work.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try [this instead](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-hide-the-menu-on-a-particular-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actual code the function to add the script is never executed. You can put the function `add_my_script()` wherever you want but you need to hook it into a Wordpress event. The best event for this case is the [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'hide-menu', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hide-menu.js', // this is the location of your script file
         array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

Your javascript code is also wrong. According to [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you are trying to select all the `<a>` elements with a href attribute that contain the substring `/it/noleggio-lungo-termine`, but such elements doesn't exist in your HTML when the laguage is not italian. The following code simply works to hide the `li` element with `id=menu-item-9452`:

```
jQuery("li#menu-item-9452").hide();
```

Read [jQuery selectors documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and use a valid selector.

To hide that element for certain languages, you will have to get access to the current language. I see that you are using qTranslate. A possible solution:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');
function add_my_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'hide-menu', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hide-menu.js', // this is the location of your script file
         array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );

    $scriptData = array(
         'lang' => qtrans_getLanguage(),
    );
    wp_localize_script('hide-menu','script_data', $scriptData);
}
```

Ant then in hide-menu.js:

```
if( script_data.lang != 'it' ) {
    jQuery("li#menu-item-9452").hide();
}
```

Also you can hide that item by CSS. For example, in the header.php of your theme you can put this code between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<?php

 if( qtrans_getLanguage() != 'it' ) {

      echo "<style>#menu-item-9452 { display: none; } </style>";

  }

?>
```

Comment: +1. I completely missed that when I edited the post. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It is the javscript file loaded? If not, check that the location of hide-menu.js file is correct in `wp_enqueue_script()` function. If the file is correctly loaded you will have to check your javascript code. If you post the HTML of the element you want to hide I can help with js code as well.

Comment: I mean that the menu isn't hide :( the link is this http://www.milanoexclusiverental.net I need to hide the top menu item "Noleggio Lungo Termine" when the language isn't italian.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: if I edit the jquery, I don't solve the problem because I have to display li element with id=menu-item-9452 when the language isn't italian. how can I fix this issue?

Comment: See edited answer and the esier alternative with css.

Comment: thank you very much! I used the alternative with css and now work fine :)